# Translating with bing using R. Error: signature "raw", "missing"

Tags: r, bing-api

I'm new to R and I'm trying to access Microsoft translator using the translate R package for R. I am able to establish a connection but I get the error :

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘fromJSON’ for signature ‘"raw", "missing"’

Here is my code:

```
options( RCurlOptions = list(verbose = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer=TRUE, sslversion=3L,  
cainfo="cacert.pem", proxy = "HOST:PORT" ))
  translate(
  content.vec = swedata,
      microsoft.client.id = "my.client.id",
      microsoft.client.secret = "my.client.secret",
      source.lang = 'sv',
      target.lang = 'en')
```

swedata is a character contaning 26 characters. (Not quite sure how that works)

```
class(swedata)
[1] "character"
class(swedata[1])
[1] "character"
```

But on to my main question.
Is the package not working propperly or could I some how "insert" the "inherited method for function ‘fromJSON’ for signature "raw", "missing" "?

I apologize in advance if the question is "blurry" as I said, I'm new to R.

Here is a traceback()

```
9: stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
   sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
8: (function (classes, fdef, mtable) 
   {
   methods <- .findInheritedMethods(classes, fdef, mtable)
   if (length(methods) == 1L) 
       return(methods[[1L]])
   else if (length(methods) == 0L) {
       cnames <- paste0("\"", sapply(classes, as.character), 
           "\"", collapse = ", ")
       stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
           sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
    }
   else stop("Internal error in finding inherited methods; didn't return a unique method", 
       domain = NA)
   })(list("raw", "missing"), function (content, handler = NULL, 
   default.size = 100, depth = 150L, allowComments = TRUE, asText = isContent(content), 
   data = NULL, maxChar = c(0L, nchar(content)), simplify = Strict, 
   nullValue = NULL, simplifyWithNames = TRUE, encoding = NA_character_, 
   stringFun = NULL, ...) 
   standardGeneric("fromJSON"), <environment>)
7: fromJSON(postForm("https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13", 
   .params = fields, style = "POST"))
6: getAccessToken(microsoft.client.id, microsoft.client.secret)
5: translate(content.vec = swedata, microsoft.client.id = "my.client.id", 
   microsoft.client.secret = "my.secret", 
   source.lang = "sv", target.lang = "en") at .active-rstudio-document#9
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("~/.active-rstudio-document", echo = TRUE)
```